# Python Dataframe - Can't replace text with a number

Tags: python, pandas

I am working Bicycle dataset. I want to replace text values in 'weather' column with numbers 1 to 4. This field is an object field. I tried all of these following ways but none seems to work.
There is another field called 'season'. If I apply same code on 'season', my code works fine. Please help.

Sample data:

```
    datetime    season  holiday workingday  weather temp    atemp   humidity    windspeed
0   5/10/2012 11:00 Summer  NaN 1   Clear + Few clouds  21.32   25.000  48  35.0008
1   6/9/2012 7:00   Summer  NaN 0   Clear + Few clouds  23.78   27.275  64  7.0015
2   3/6/2011 20:00  Spring  NaN 0   Light Snow, Light Rain  11.48   12.120  100 27.9993
3   10/13/2011 11:00    Winter  NaN 1   Mist + Cloudy   25.42   28.790  83  0.0000
4   6/2/2012 12:00  Summer  NaN 0   Clear + Few clouds  25.42   31.060  43  23.9994
```

I tried following, none worked on 'weather' but when i use same code on 'season' column it works fine.

```
test["weather"] = np.where(test["weather"]=="Clear + Few clouds", 1, 
(np.where(test["weather"]=="Mist + Cloudy",2,(np.where(test["weather"]=="Light Snow, Light 
Rain",3,(np.where(test["weather"]=="Heavy Rain + Thunderstorm",4,0))))))) 

PE_weather = [
    (train['weather'] == ' Clear + Few clouds '),
    (train['weather'] =='Mist + Cloudy') ,
    (train['weather'] >= 'Light Snow, Light Rain'),
    (train['weather'] >= 'Heavy Rain + Thunderstorm')]
PE_weather_value = ['1', '2', '3','4']
train['Weather'] = np.select(PE_weather, PE_weather_value)

test.loc[test.weather =='Clear + Few clouds', 'weather']='1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you make a dictionary to look up the corresponding values and then apply a lookup to the weather column.

```py
weather_lookup = {
    'Clear + Few clouds': 1,
    'Mist + Cloudy': 2,
    'Light Snow, Light Rain': 3,
    'Heavy Rain + Thunderstorm': 4
}

def lookup(w):
    return weather_lookup.get(w, 0)

test['weather'] = test['weather'].apply(lookup)
```

Output:

```
           datetime  season  holiday  workingday  weather   temp   atemp     humidity  windspeed 
0   5/10/2012 11:00  Summer      NaN           1        1  21.32  25.000           48    35.0008   
1     6/9/2012 7:00  Summer      NaN           0        1  23.78  27.275           64     7.0015   
2    3/6/2011 20:00  Spring      NaN           0        3  11.48  12.120  100 27.9993        NaN   
3  10/13/2011 11:00  Winter      NaN           1        2  25.42  28.790           83     0.0000   
4    6/2/2012 12:00  Summer      NaN           0        1  25.42  31.060           43    23.9994
```

Comment: Thanks Tobi208!!!!! Much appreciated. After trying approach suggested by you, I realized that there are spaces at the beginning and and end of some of these values. I used test['weather'] = test['weather'].str.strip() before running your code and it worked like a charm. I tried all other ways and all of them actually worked. However, I liked your idea, ones you have it you can apply it on multiple datasets. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome :) Please mark the answer as accepted then to close the question.